# An eye for style

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

My colour-blind friend and I play in the same Dungeons and Dragons campaign. Our party had just died in a horrendously managed battle against a dracolisk (seriously, don't ask!) and so we were back to rolling up new characters before the next session.

After much internal debate, I finally decided to play an elven cleric who is 'totally about fashion' and would attempt to purchase new clothing in each town we would pass through.  For once, I wanted her to have a name she could wear with pride (my late halfling bard, Squoggle, had never been taken seriously!)

Since I am so terrible at naming, I sent my friend a text for help with a name.  Some time later, instead of an answer, I ended up receiving the following image:

[image]

**What does my friend think I should name my character?**

**As a bonus, what job do you think my friend has?**

Note / Hint:

> This puzzle is in homage to my friend who is colour-blind and actually could solve it with only what you have above.

Apologies if you think this is a terrible puzzle... constructive feedback is appreciated. :)

Hint 1:

> Why would anyone add coloured squares to an image?

Hint 2:

> My friend finds naming things even more useful than I do.

Hint 3:

> There is another applicable tag for this puzzle that I haven't added.  I am sure it will become obvious when that step is in front of you!

Hint 4:

> Purists may think (as do I) that the last step doesn’t really deserve the missing tag... but the puzzle and the story bring their own lenses on what is left to solve.

Hint 5:

> The final step contains three different ways to get the same answer.

Comment: Hi Graylocke, does this puzzle require some in depth knowledge of D and D at all?

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: Answers are 1) No and 2) Certainly!

Comment: Should a cipher tag be added?

Comment: Seems like a thing I should have done.  Also I know for a fact that there is one more tag that could be added that I haven't added.

Comment: I'm not colour-blind, but I'm finding it very hard to tell the difference between the two leftmost colours.

Comment: Ah, I know exactly what the other tag would have been now! One step to go...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Mmm - but my colour-blind friend also can't tell them easily either... Tedious as it may be.

Comment: What type of colorblind does your friend have?

Comment: It isn’t relevant @Anonymus25 , but Deutoranomia (red-green) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your friend is suggesting you should use the name:

> **IRIS**

The first thing to do here is:

> identify the 6 colours used in the making of this cipher. These are (reading the 6 squares from left to right):
>
>  **REBECCA PURPLE**
>  **DARK SLATE BLUE**
>  **LIGHT SEA GREEN**
>  **LEMON CHIFFON**
>  **SANDY BROWN**
>  **LIGHT CORAL**
>
>  (And yes, I had to use a colour 'eye dropper' to find the RGB codes and then search for the corresponding colour name online.)

What we then need to do is:

> assign numbers to the letters in each colour name, starting with 1. Then for each number, read off the letter with that index. For example, the first digit is 2 and is coloured with 'DARK SLATE BLUE' - this would translate to 'A', the 2nd letter of the colour name.

The message then decodes to:

> **ARCH GODDESS OPENS CENTRE LIKE A FLOWER**
>
>  (Note that the '1' and '3' at the end of the fifth word need to be read together as '13'...)

What is this? Surely, it's:

> a **cryptic crossword clue** (of sorts)! Specifically, it's a *triple definition*, where three parts point to different meanings of **IRIS**:
>
>  **ARCH GODDESS** - in Greek mythology, [Iris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(mythology)) was the *goddess* of the rainbow (an *arch* of colour);
>
>  **OPENS CENTRE** - changes in shape of the [iris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(anatomy)) of the eye cause the pupil (at its *centre*) to *open* and close, controlling the amount of light that enters. This also explains the relevance of **eye** in the title!
>
>  **LIKE A FLOWER** - an [iris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(plant)) is also a species of flower!

As to your friend's career, I wouldn't be at all surprised if they are a:

> **web developer**, as there are very few other careers in which one would need to use colour names this specifically!

Comment: I had the right idea all along. I just could not work out the colours smh. Also maybe the friend could be working for a paint company.

Comment: Rebecca purple??

Comment: You must have great skills with google lol have an upvote.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I find the [convertingcolors](https://convertingcolors.com/) website is very useful for identifying things like this...

Comment: I think trying to solve this puzzle on my android was a bad idea...

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Yes, [Rebecca purple](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Eric_A._Meyer#/Personal_life). Last paragraph of the section Personal Life.

Comment: @Stiv Very good!  One step to go!  perhaps rot13(gurer ner bgure jnlf nepurf znl eryngr gb gur chmmyr)

Comment: @Graylocke Think I've got it at last! :)

Comment: What would the other tag have been?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I would guess [tag:cryptic-clues]

Comment: @Stiv Good job :) It wasn’t the best of clues but I was having trouble with the letters and keeping the theme together. After all, it has to be a name to wear with pride. :)

Comment: And yes @Voldemort’s Wrath / @Stiv : cryptic-clues was what I was thinking of (mind you - it’s pretty rubbish for that tag tbh!)